# Spring data jpa @Onetomany isssue

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
class Hospital{

@Id     
@GeneratedValue 
Private long hospitalId

Private String name;

Private string password;

@Embaded
Private Address address;

@Onetomany(mappedby=Hospital)
Private List<Department> department;

}

@Entity
class Department {

@Id     
@GeneratedValue 

private Long depId;

Private String department;

@Manytoone

@JoinColumn(name="hospitalId")

Private Hospital hospital

}
```

Here scenario is like first Hospital register with name,password,address after logging only Hospital will enter department details.
I want to insert only  foriegn key to department entity while hospital get register and getting details of department from specific hospital I want to update the department entity using foreign key how to implement it using spring data jpa

Answer (score 0):

Try to add cascade

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "class", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
```

Cascade help you to insert and update using entity foreign key, 
there is a diffirent value of cascade type:

- ALL
- PERSIST
- MERGE
- REMOVE
- REFRESH
- DETACH

Reference [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types) to understand all cases with its purpose.

I hope that will help.

Comment: But there will no department object there while hospital get registering .hospital can add only after logging only

Comment: Yup, but in your question in the line before last `I want to update the department entity using foreign key` so this answer based on your question.
 So if you want to insert department you can add or update it directly using hospital entity reference

Comment: Please make sure if i understand your question or not, And sorry if my answer is wrong.

Comment: Problem is whenever I am inserting Hospital details hospitalId which is foreign key in Department entity is not inserting if it get inserted I think I can update other field using this foreign key

Comment: In cascade, you can insert the department directly from hospital so after the hospital registered, you can create a new department and add it to list, and to make sure the department is with relation ship with hospital, add optinal like `@ManyToOne(optional = false,...) `.

I'm not sure if that help or not(Or I understand your case or not)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Hospital")
class Hospital{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Private long hospitalId

    Private String name;

    Private string password;

    @Embedded
    Private Address address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hospital", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    Private List<Department> department;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Department")
class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long depId;

    Private String department;


    @JoinColumn(name = "hospitalId")
    @ManyToOne()
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    Private Hospital hospital;

}
```